# Названия грибов

Tags: этимология

Как правило, большая часть грибов, которые растут в наших лесах, имеют русские и вполне понятные названия: подосиновик, опенок, масленок, волнушка и т. д. Но некоторые названия, видимо, имеют то ли старорусские, то ли диалектные корни, поэтому я не могу их понять. Например, такие названия, как груздь, валуй, плютей или гриб со странным названием говорушка (надеюсь, он не разговаривает).
Было бы очень интересно узнать происхождение этих названий. А еще интересно, почему так назвали мухомор — с его помощью действительно морили мух?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Названия грибов чаще всего носят диалектный характер и могут сильно отличаться даже в разных районах одной области. Что касается приведенных вами названий, то, кроме груздя и мухомора, мне ни одно не известно. "Груздь" скорей всего родственен слову "гроздь", а "мухомор" действительно использовали для травли мух: настойку из мухоморов ставили подальше от людей, мухи слетались на нее и погибали.

Answer (score -1):

Происхождение слова «груздь» этимологи связывают со значениями *груда*,  *громоздит*ь, *громоздкий*, т. е. это гриб, растущий на груде.

По одной из версий название «говорушка» происходит от кучности произрастания грибов этого рода, позволяющей вести между собой бесконечные разговоры.

Comment: Редактируйте старый ответ, а не пиштье новый.